# Tic Tac Toe game in Java vs computer

Tags: java, array, tic-tac-toe, ai

I am trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game in Java using a 2 dimensional array. The computer has to do the smartest move.

```
/* This program creates an interactive game of Tic-Tac-Toe
 * The computer is able to play intelligently and block the user and try to win
 * It uses a 2D array to create a grid for the game
 * The user makes their moves using a coordinate system
 */


//for the Scanner
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe {

    private static boolean first = false;
    private static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    private static int aiScore = 0;
    private static int playerScore = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        intro();

    }

    public static void intro(){

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe");
        System.out.println("To play this classic game against the computer,");
        System.out.println("You will choose where to play using coordinates(1-3)");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Would you like to go first?");
        String goFirst = console.nextLine();

        if(goFirst.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            first = true;
        }
        initializeBoard();
        getBoard();
        startGame(console);


    }


    public static void startGame(Scanner console){

        //clears the board to start the game


        if(first == true){
            userTurn(console);
        }else{
            compTurn(console);
        }
    }

    //allows user to play
    public static void userTurn(Scanner console){
        System.out.println("Where would you like to play?");

        int r = console.nextInt() - 1;
        int c = console.nextInt() - 1;

        if(board[r][c] == ' '){
            board[r][c] = 'X';

            if(board[0][0] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 1;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[0][2] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 3;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[2][0] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 1000;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[2][2] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 3000;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[1][1] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 200;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[0][1] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 2;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[1][0] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 100;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[1][2] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 300;
                checkScoreUser(console);

            } else if(board[2][1] == 'X'){
                getBoard();
                playerScore += 2000;
                checkScoreUser(console);
            }

        } else if (board[r][c] == 'X' || board[r][c] == 'O'){
            first = true;
            System.out.println("Please choose an empty space");
            startGame(console);
        }

        System.out.println("Cat's Game");

    }


    //allows computer to play
    public static void compTurn(Scanner console){

        System.out.println("Now it's my turn");
        System.out.println("");

        if(board[0][0] == ' '){
            board[0][0] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 1;

        } else if(board[0][2] == ' '){
            board[0][2] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 3;

        } else if(board[2][0] == ' '){
            board[2][0] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 1000;

        } else if(board[2][2] == ' '){
            board[2][2] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 3000;

        } else if(board[1][1] == ' '){
            board[1][1] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 200;

        } else if(board[0][1] == ' '){
            board[0][1] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 2;

        } else if(board[1][0] == ' '){
            board[1][0] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 100;

        } else if(board[1][2] == ' '){
            board[1][2] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 300;

        } else if(board[2][1] == ' '){
            board[2][1] = 'O';
            getBoard();
            userTurn(console);
            aiScore += 2000;
        }       


    }

    /*public static void checkUser(Scanner console){

        if(playerScore == 3){
            board[0][2] = 'O';
        } else if (playerScore ==)

    }*/



    //score checkers
    public static void checkScoreUser(Scanner console){
        if(aiScore == 3201 || aiScore == 1203 || aiScore == 6 ||
                aiScore == 600 || aiScore == 6000 || aiScore == 1101 || 
                        aiScore == 2202 || aiScore == 3303){
            System.out.println("I win!!! Hahahahahaha!!!!!!");
            intro();

        } else if (playerScore == 3201 || playerScore == 1203 || playerScore == 6 ||
                playerScore == 600 || playerScore == 6000 || playerScore == 1101 || 
                playerScore == 2202 || playerScore == 3303){
            System.out.println("You won!");
            intro();
        } else {
            compTurn(console);
        }
    }
    public static void checkScoreComp(Scanner console){
        if(aiScore == 3201 || aiScore == 1203 || aiScore == 6 ||
                aiScore == 600 || aiScore == 6000 || aiScore == 1101 || 
                        aiScore == 2202 || aiScore == 3303){
            System.out.println("I win!!! Hahahahahaha!!!!!!");
            intro();

        } else if (playerScore == 3201 || playerScore == 1203 || playerScore == 6 ||
                playerScore == 600 || playerScore == 6000 || playerScore == 1101 || 
                playerScore == 2202 || playerScore == 3303){
            System.out.println("You won!");
            intro();
        } else {
            userTurn(console);
        }
    }



    //board stuff

    //initializes board and fills it with black spaces
    public static void initializeBoard(){

        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
                board[r][c] = ' ';
            }
        }

    }
    //prints the actual board out
    public static void getBoard(){

        String bar = "  =============";
        System.out.println("    1   2   3");
        System.out.println(bar);
        System.out.println("1   " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2]);
        System.out.println(bar);
        System.out.println("2   " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2]);
        System.out.println(bar);
        System.out.println("3   " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2]);
        System.out.println(bar);
        System.out.println("");


    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please keep in mind that implementing new features (as you asked in the initial version of the question) is out of our scope, as explained on [on-topic](/help/on-topic). We can review the current code and help you make it better.

Comment: "I am trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game in Java" Did you succeed? Does it work as intended?

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 5 → 4.

Answer (score 3):

This transcript below shows the win detection is buggy.

> ```
> $ java TicTacToe
>
>
> Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe
> To play this classic game against the computer,
> You will choose where to play using coordinates(1-3)
>
> Would you like to go first?
> n
>     1   2   3
>   =============
> 1     |   |  
>   =============
> 2     |   |  
>   =============
> 3     |   |  
>   =============
>
> Now it's my turn
>
>     1   2   3
>   =============
> 1   O |   |  
>   =============
> 2     |   |  
>   =============
> 3     |   |  
>   =============
>
> Where would you like to play?
> 1 3
>     1   2   3
>   =============
> 1   O |   | X
>   =============
> 2     |   |  
>   =============
> 3     |   |  
>   =============
>
> Now it's my turn
>
>     1   2   3
>   =============
> 1   O |   | X
>   =============
> 2     |   |  
>   =============
> 3   O |   |  
>   =============
>
> Where would you like to play?
> 2 1
>     1   2   3
>   =============
> 1   O |   | X
>   =============
> 2   X |   |  
>   =============
> 3   O |   |  
>   =============
>
> You won!
> ```

Huh, what?  That is way too early for the AI to forfeit!